# Extract PKCS12 file from Java Keystore while changing the password using keytool

Tags: java, security, keytool, pkcs#12, jks

I have a Java Keystore: `myKeystore.jks`, and given an alias : `someAlias`, I'm trying to extract the corresponding resource in a `p12` format while changing the password.

The JKS password is `12345678` which is the same password as the someAlias key.

I want my p12 file to be protected with the new password : `1122334455`

### What I've tried :

> keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore myKeystore.jks -destkeystore
>   test.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12 -srcalias someAlias -srcstorepass
>   12345678 -deststorepass 1122334455

In this case the `test.p12` is exported, but I'm unable to read it because either the password is incorrect OR the file is corrupted.

[image]

But when I try this (Keeping the same password) :

> keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore myKeystore.jks -destkeystore
>   test.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12 -srcalias someAlias -srcstorepass
>   12345678 -deststorepass 12345678

I can open my `test.p12` file with the given password.

**P.S : I also tried to add the -srckeypass argument, but no luck.**

**P.S 2 : I'm using keystore explorer 5.11 to open my stores**

What am I missing ?

Comment: You'll have to show the command that gave the error with the .p12 file, and the error message itself, *verbatim,* not a paraphrase.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have only changed the password of the key*store* with the first command. The password for the *key* is still 12345678.

While it is possible for PKCS#12 to have different passwords for container/content, it is a bad idea because most applications assume that the passwords are equal (which is the reason why KeyStore Explorer shows that error message).

To change the password for the key you have to add `-destkeypass`:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore myKeystore.jks -destkeystore myKeystore.p12 
-deststoretype PKCS12 -srcalias someAlias -srcstorepass 12345678 -deststorepass 
1122334455 -destkeypass 1122334455
```

BTW, since Java 8 keytool shows an error message for your command:

> keytool error: java.lang.Exception: The destination pkcs12 keystore has different storepass and keypass. Please retry with -destkeypass specified.

Comment: -destkeypass solved the problem, I'm using JAVA 7, the command is executed successfully.